# SBT Comple DependsOn Multiple Tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT if I want my Task Foo to be executed before compile I can do

```
(Compile / compile) := ((Compile / compile) dependsOn Foo).value
```

But what if I want compile to depend on 3 tasks instead of 1. (Foo Bar Baz)?

I tried

```
(Compile / compile) : ((Compile / compile) dependsOn Foo, Bar, Baz).value
```

but the above doesn't work

How do I set dependency on multiple tasks. Foo, Bar and Baz are independent and they can run in parallel if possible. the only requirement is that compile should happen once Foo, Bar, Baz have successfully run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dependsOn`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/sbt/std/SingleInTask.html#dependsOn(tasks:sbt.Task[_]*):sbt.Task[S]) takes variable arguments, so you can pass several tasks to it. The problem is only in the wrong syntax. Here's how to fix it:

```
Compile/compile := (Compile/compile).dependsOn(Foo, Bar, Baz).value
```

This is a general thing in Scala, you can call any method either `foo.method(arg)` or `foo method arg`. You can still use the second form, but then you should write `Compile/compile dependsOn (Foo, Bar, Baz)`, which doesn't make much difference, but may require adding parentheses for calling `value` on it.

Comment: error: value / is not a member of sbt.Configuration
   `Compile/compile := Compile/compile.dependsOn(Foo, Bar).value`

Comment: My bad. `Compile/compile` on the right side needs to be surrounded in parentheses. I updated the answer.

Comment: By the way, you can also call `dependsOn` several times. This is more verbose, but still valid.